# Retrieving class inside a method using reflection

Tags: java, class, oop, reflection, local-class

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new test();
    }
    void method() {
         class inside {
              int a;
              void methodinside() {}
         }
    }
}
```

I was declaring class using reflection like:

```
Class c = Class.forName("test");
Class[] cls = c.getDeclaredClasses();
for(Class cl : cls)
     System.out.println(cl.getName());
```

but, my program cannot find `class inside`.

Comment: Interesting, since we can do the reverse with `getEnclosingClass`. http://ideone.com/nA3Zua

Comment: how to access in main, while class inside in another method or another class ???

Comment: If you want to access the class from `main` then you have to declare it somewhere where `main` can see it. The point of these local classes is to not be visible from outside the declaring method.

Comment: any idea or other way beside reflection ???

Comment: This could be an X-Y-problem. What are you really trying to do? Are you developing some kind of IDE tooling?

Comment: yes, i want developing some code to some diagram like classes diagram and others.

this is only my problem, i had tool like class visualizer also cannot loading local class too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a method to find local classes (classes defined inside a method).

You could [try to enumerate all classes in the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) and then use getEnclosingClass (the opposite of what you are looking for) to filter them.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to enumerate all classes in a package either.

Comment: try you see on class files. there are created file test$1inside.class

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to get Inner class in a method.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Outer$1InnerMethodClass");
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());

        clazz = Class.forName("Outer$2InnerMethodClass");
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());

        clazz = Class.forName("Outer$2InnerMethodClass$1InnerMethodInnetMethod");
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    }

}

class Outer{
    void outerMethod1() {
        class InnerMethodClass {
             int a;
             void innerMethod() {}
        }
   }

    void outerMethod2() {
        class InnerMethodClass {
             int a;
             void innerMethod() {
                 class InnerMethodInnetMethod{

                 }
             }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This can't be safely generalized though. The exact name of a local class is not mandated by the specification, only its format.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there aren't general methods for enumerating classes by design. This is because classes could be loaded from anywhere, or dynamically created. Storing class files in a JAR or directory is just one of any possible class loaders.

So, while it might be more reasonable to assume that enclosed classes are a known, enumerable set, it doesn't make sense to provide a method that works only in that special case.

If you assume the common case of a `URLClassLoader`, you can treat the underlying URLs as file systems and enumerate their contents. This might be appropriate if you are creating a tool to do something with existing third-party code, and it has even been adopted for many Java EE standards (mistakenly, I feel).

If you are creating a plug-in mechanism, [providing metadata in a well-known location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) is more efficient, reliable, and works with any valid class loader.

Answer (score 1):

The `getDeclaredClasses()` method returns (from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses%28%29))-

> an array of Class objects reflecting all the classes and interfaces
>   declared as members of the class represented by this Class object.
>   This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   classes and interfaces declared by the class, but excludes inherited
>   classes and interfaces.

So it seems it doesn't return any inner class you have declared. That's why you get nothing in the array of `Class` `cls`.